# Why the picklist is disabled

Tags: custom-object, picklist, mavensmate

I'm using custom object `Employee__c` and I have added a new field called type = picklist for `State` when I go to the page to create a new records the picklist (State) shows in disabled mode and I do not see I have any Field Dependencies or Validation Rules. So what might be the case?

here is the sample of the State picklist.

```
  <fields>
    <fullName>State__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>State</label>
    <picklist>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>Alabama</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>Alaska</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues> 
        //more.....
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>California</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues> 
        <sorted>false</sorted>
    </picklist>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Picklist</type>
</fields>
```

Comment: I would suspect field level security or page layout. Can you double check those?

Comment: in the field level security i have all checked to visible and what exactly I will be looking in the page layout?

Comment: For picklist to be editable on field level security you should have read only unchecked.
Regarding page layout, open the page layout -> go to the field -> click on the wrench -> make sure read only is not ticked.

Comment: read-only is not checked ... not sure what else do I need to look

Comment: Does the object has a record type? Is there any value selected for that particular record type?

Comment: yes this object does have a record type but i am not sure i understand the last part of your question

Comment: When record types are enabled for an object, each Record Type controls the specific picklist values available for each picklist field. So, in your metadata example above you've only added the picklist values to the picklist field, but not made any of those available to the record types. In the UI, go the record types and then click Edit on this picklist field (under the record type). From there you can see which values are assigned to it. Make the adjustments, save, and then refresh your metadata to see how that's represented in the .object file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed my issue

The reason why it was disabled is because there was no values selected.

Steps:

1. Go to the Custom Object (you having issue with) and View the
   Record Types
2. Click on the Record Type Label
3. Click on the
   field (having issue with) from the `PickList Available for Editing`
4. Make sure the `Selected Values` have some values selected
5. Repeat if you have more than one Record Types

In my case there were no Selected Values selected.

Hope this will help others.